# Сворачивание\разворачивание таблицы

Tags: javascript

Реализовано сворачивание\разворачивание таблицы при нажатии на кнопку. Почему первая таблица работает как надо, а ее копия ниже не работает? https://jsfiddle.net/xzr72h0y/12/

```
let trL = $('tr').length;
let trW = +$('tr:nth-child(2)').css('height').replace(/\D/g, '');
let trFirst = +$('tr:first-child').css('height').replace(/\D/g, '');
let wrapper = $('#wrapper');

wrapper.css({
  'height': trW * 3 + trFirst + 'px'
});
let sh = $('#sh');

sh.on('click', function (e) {
  if($(this).text() === 'Show') {
    $(this).text('Hide');
    wrapper.animate({
      height: $('table').height()
    });
  } else {
    $(this).text('Show');
    wrapper.animate({
      height: trW * 3 + trFirst + 'px'
    });
  }
});

sh.css({display: 'block'});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/75xbv8n9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id - уникальный индификатор. А Вы используете его 2 разу. Он идет к первому (либо вообще ошибка, не знаю таких тонкостей).
Используйте для второго разворачивания другой id, либо перейдите на класс (но нужно будет поменять логику, т к js будет видить последний класс с таким именем)